# Universal covering space of connected open subset of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Is the universal covering of an open connected subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$  homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example, let $n=3$ and $U=\Bbb{R}^3\setminus \{(0,0,0)\}$. Then the universal cover of $U$ is $U$ itself (since it's simply connected) which is not homoemorphic to $\Bbb{R}^3$ (since it has nontrivial $2$-homology say).

Comment: For the more difficult case where we ask if $U$ is homeomorphic to _some_ open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ (not necessarily all of $\Bbb R^n$), see this MathOverflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18195/is-the-universal-covering-of-an-open-subset-of-mathbbrn-diffeomorphic-to-an. The answer is still no in this case, see Ryan Budney's example in the link.

Comment: thanks for answering. I want to know is it true for the case $n=2$?

Comment: Oh, I got it. this problem is true for the $n=2$. By the uniformazation theorem every simply connected Rimaneian  surface is biholomorphic with on of three case: Rimaneian sphere, open unit ball or complex plane, So the problem for this case is true.